# var_dump($_POST) give a string not array

Tags: php

please can some one help me with this  when i 
 `var_dump($_POST)` i get my array into a string

```
string(202) "array('0' => '{"nom":"Pull suave","prix":7,"count":2}', '1' => '{"nom":"Robe Africaine","prix":89,"count":1}', '2' => '{"nom":"Tabie","prix":56,"count":1}', '3' => '{"nom":"tabie","prix":99,"count":1}')"
```

just i want to know how to get this array into this string
i searched everywhere a solution an now i want to know if someone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to capture the contents of `$_POST` as a string, there are a couple of different ways you can do this.

1. Use [serialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).
2. If you want a string in the same format as `var_dump()`, use output buffers:

`ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$myString = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: i need an array with post but i get an array into a string how to get this array???

Comment: `$_POST` is an array by default - you can use it as-is. If you're getting a string instead, when you are expecting an array,  it's because you overwrote it somewhere.